# Rails server command JavaScript runtime error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

I just started learning Ruby on rails and everything works fine until when I 
run the server also I reinstalled Nodejs and no lock. i'm on windows 10.
also I tried : `gem update` , `bundle install`, `gem bundle install`.
I ran all commands on Git bash.

```
            $ rails server
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
            Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
            Backtrace for gem load error is:
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
            c:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
            c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
            bin/rails:4:in `require'
            bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
            Bundler Error Backtrace:
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
                    from c:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
                    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
                    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
                    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: One of the easiest solutions is to install `node`. http://nodejs.org/

Comment: i did that and still no luck

Comment: Are you getting the same error even after installing node? Did you add node to the `PATH` variable?

Comment: i just ran the installer , how can i add node to path variable?

Comment: Try `node -v` and if you get a number back, node path was added to PATH environmental variable by the installer. Reopen the command prompt window and try to start the rails server.

Comment: running it with Command prompt worked! thanks , but why it doesnt work with git bash?

Answer (score -1):

as  Arun Kumar said , running with command prompt Configured everything. so running Rails server using Command prompt worked.